# Android tool adb stand alone or a lightweight alternative of the "whole sdk" solution

Tags: android, command-line, sdk, adb

I like the android adb tool, but to have it I need Java and the whole Android SDK installed in my environment. I was wondering if it was an smaller solution that can substitute the adb command line tool.

I need it to be command line and to have install and push commands.

Thanks!

Comment: `adb` is pretty lightweight as it is http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb

Comment: Thank you i actually was checking that thread!